# Passport JWT works with empty payload

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I have initialized strategy for JWT:

```
const jwtStrategyOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('x-access-token'),
  secretOrKey: 'publicKey',
}

passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(
    jwtStrategyOptions,
    (payload, done) => {
      MySQL.Users.readOne(['id'], { id: payload.userId })
      .fork(
        error => {console.log(error)
          done(error)},
        user => {
          console.log(user)
          done(null, user)}
      )
    }
  )
)
```

And middleware:

```
const isAuthenticated: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate(
    'jwt',
    { session: false, failWithError: true },
    (error, user) => {
      //error is null when I pass empty payload
      if (error) {
        return next(error)
      }
      req.user = user

      return next()
    }
  )(req, res, next)
}
```

But when I pass empty or invalid token Passport just pass this

```
(payload, done) => {
  MySQL.Users.readOne(['id'], { id: payload.userId })
  .fork(
    error => {console.log(error)
      done(error)},
    user => {
      console.log(user)
      done(null, user)}
  )
}
```

step and code execute `next()` function.
Can I somehow detect that payload is invalid or empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the MySQL call return type, but if nothing matches the id, does it raise an error?

```
(payload, done) => {
  MySQL.Users.readOne(['id'], { id: payload.userId })
  .fork(
    error => {console.log(error)
      done(error)},
    user => {
      console.log(user)
      done(null, user)}
  )
}
```

If it doesn't raise an error but return null or empty value, you need to check it in the 'success' callback function, because in this case it will call `done(null, user)` with an empty value.

Based on your comment, this might help, some code that I was using to check for a token expiration error :

```
    passport.authenticate('jwt',
        {session: false},
        //we need this callback to return information on why it's failing
        //err is not populated, but 'info' is...
        (err, user, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            //if we couldn't authenticate the user, check why
            //401 is used when no token or random information is provided
            //403 is used when a well-formed token is provided, but it has expired thus not valid anymore
            if (!user) {
                if (info.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                    return res.status(403).send(info.name);
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(401).send(info.message);
                }
            }

            req.user = user;

            return next();
```

Comment: When I pass valid token everything works fine and I get user from db, but when I pass not valid or empty token it just skip callback function with DB select in it, and error in passport.authenticate method equal to null.

Comment: Ok I see, I updated my answer. Hopefully it helps :D

Comment: i'm kinda confused, why is the err not populated when there's a TokenExpiredError? Shouldn't it be considered as an error? I'm currently trying to intercept if token has expired and error is always empty but info says something has an error just like with your code.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer I think that the `err` object is used when there's an actual error in the authenticate function and `info` is detailed information on the token's data. An expired token is still a 'valid' token in terms of parsing etc...

Comment: @HRK44 yup, but it's just a little unintuitive that way. It would have been better if the errors thrown by jsonwebtoken package under the hood are being caught